# Build json string from representative input

Tags: java, json, algorithm, data-structures

Can somebody direct me to a right approach ?
Do I need first to create a tree after parsing the input and then trasverse it ?

The input is given in the following form:

```
node11/node12/.../node1k 
node21/node22/.../node2n 
...
nodem1/nodem2/.../nodeml
```

Sample input:

```
a/b/c1 
x/b 
a/b/c/d
m
```

Output:

```
{
  a: {
    b: {
      c: { d: "" },
      c1: "" 
        }
       },
  x: { b: "" },
  m: ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a JS solution that uses recursion to process each path.

```js
function parse(paths) {
  var resultObj = {};
  paths.forEach(function(path) {
    var nodes = path.split("/");
    recurse(nodes, resultObj);
  });
  console.log(resultObj);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(resultObj));
}

function recurse(path, obj) {
  if (!path.length)
    return obj;
  var node = path.shift();
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(node))
    obj[node] = path.length ? {} : "";
  return recurse(path, obj[node]);
}

var arr = ["a/b/c1", "x/b", "a/b/c/d", "m"];
parse(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in python, you could do this:

```
output = {}
lines = ["a/b/c1", "x/b", "a/b/c/d", "m"]
for line in lines:
    nodePath = line.split('/')
    current = output
    for node in nodePath[:-1]:
        current[node] = {} if node not in current else current[node]
        current = current[node]
    current[nodePath[-1]] = ""

print output # gives us {'a': {'b': {'c1': '', 'c': {'d': ''}}}, 'x': {'b': ''}, 'm': ''}
```

Then turn output into json however you want.